# How to overwrite object variables

Tags: javascript

I'd like to configure a Javascript object using a syntax something like JQuery .ajax(..) one and not with a list of parameters, only defining values different from defaults.
So far I wrote it like:

```
function ObjFn(config) {
  var var1 = 200  
  var var2 = "qwerty"
  var var3 = 555

  if (config instanceof Object){
    console.log("-> config")
    if (config.var1 !== undefined) var1 = config.var1
    if (config.var2 !== undefined) var2 = config.var2
    if (config.var3 !== undefined) var3 = config.var3
  }

  this.describe = function(){
    console.log("var1: "+var1+" - "+"var2: "+var2+" - "+"var3: "+var3+" - "+"config: "+config+"\n")
  }
}
```

But I'm wondering if it is possible to avoid writing a list of conditionals:

```
if (confing.var !== undefined) var = config.var
```

For each possible overwritable variable but simply using in some way the name of the variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could destructure `config` into the `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` variables, using default property values. If `config` isn't an object, destructure from an empty object instead so that those default parameters will be used:

```js
function ObjFn(config) {
  const { var1=200, var2="querty", var3=555} =
    config instanceof Object
    ? config
    : {};
  this.describe = function(){
    console.log("var1: "+var1+" - "+"var2: "+var2+" - "+"var3: "+var3+" - "+"config: "+config+"\n")
  }
}
const instance = new ObjFn({ var1: 333 });
instance.describe();

const instance2 = new ObjFn();
instance2.describe();
```

If the parameter, if passed, will always be an object, you can destructure in the parameter list instead:

```js
function ObjFn({ var1=200, var2="querty", var3=555} = {}) {
  this.describe = function(){
    console.log("var1: "+var1+" - "+"var2: "+var2+" - "+"var3: "+var3)
  }
}
const instance = new ObjFn({ var1: 333 });
instance.describe();

const instance2 = new ObjFn();
instance2.describe();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an object to hold your variables and use `Object.assign()` to merge the config object to your default values, however this could add new properties to your `vars` object:

```js
function ObjFn(config) {
  const vars = Object.assign({
    var1: 200,
    var2: 'qwerty',
    var3: 555
  }, config);

  this.describe = function() {
    const str = Object.entries(vars).map(([k, v]) => `${k}: ${v}`).join(' - ');
    console.log(str);
  }
}

new ObjFn({ var2: 'azerty', newProp: 'hello' }).describe();
new ObjFn({ var1: 1, var3: 0 }).describe();
new ObjFn().describe();
```

If you do not want to add new properties, iterate over the properties of your `vars` object and set them from the config if the entry exists:

```js
function ObjFn(config) {
  const vars = {
    var1: 200,
    var2: 'qwerty',
    var3: 555
  };

  if (config instanceof Object) {
    for (let prop in vars) {
      if (config.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        vars[prop] = config[prop];
      }
    }
  }

  this.describe = function() {
    const str = Object.entries(vars).map(([k, v]) => `${k}: ${v}`).join(' - ');
    console.log(str);
  }
}

new ObjFn({ var2: 'azerty', newProp: 'hello' }).describe();
new ObjFn({ var1: 1, var3: 0 }).describe();
new ObjFn().describe();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Simple and clean:

```
function ObjFn(config) {
    var var1 = config.var1 || 200  
    var var2 = config.var2 || "qwerty"
    var var3 = config.var3 || 555

    this.describe = function(){
        console.log("var1: "+var1+" - "+"var2: "+var2+" - "+"var3: "+var3+" - "+"config: "+config+"\n")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an `extend` function which takes an object as its first argument, then adds properties from all other passed objects which are not present in the first object. This is how a lot of jQuery's methods work under the hood (using [`jQuery.extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)):

```js
function extend(obj) {
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        for (var key in arguments[i]) {
            if (arguments[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                obj[key] = arguments[i][key];
            }
        }
    }

    return obj;
}

function ObjFn(config) {
    var params = {
        var1: 200,
        var2: 'qwerty',
        var3: 555
    };

    if (config instanceof Object) {
        console.log("-> config");
        extend(params, config);
    }

    this.describe = function () {
        console.log("var1: " + params.var1 + " - " + "var2: " + params.var2 + " - " + "var3: " + params.var3 + " - " + "config: " + config + "\n");
    }
}

var instance = new ObjFn({var1: 999});
instance.describe();

var instance2 = new ObjFn();
instance2.describe();
```